# How does the operating system recognize a printer on the LAN?

Tags: printer, lan

My printer is connected to the router using wifi, how does my laptop recognize there is a printer?
I understand that since the printer is connected to the router it has an ip address, but how does the OS know that it's a printer and not some other computer on the lan? does it ask everyone "are a printer?"

How does it work?

Comment: This depends on the OS, the printer, and the capabilities and features of the WAN. Giving more information may allow us to give you a better answer.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 on my laptop. the printer is connected to the router, does it really matter what model it is? usually windows manage to recognize it , I'm wondering how it does so...

Comment: The general topic is network discovery. There are many higher-level implementations but the underlying technology is broadcast or multicast.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different ways, but most likely what you're seeing is SMB registration. Some device (typically a PC running Windows, but not always) is elected as the master browser for the network and it periodically broadcasts its status. Devices that offer SMB services hear the broadcast and register with the master browser. Computers can also query the master browser for the list of registered services.

See [browser service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_service) for more details. Note that Windows is definitely not the only operating system to offer and use this service.

It could also be [bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) or mDNS. There are several technologies that can do this and many devices support more than one of them.